# Which quantifier should I use?

Tags: quantifiers

Are these two sentences equivalent? Are they both correct?

> "There are a *little* more than 1,000 inhabitants."
> "There are a *few* more than 1,000 inhabitants."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all kinds of ways of saying this, depending on what nuance you want to place upon it.

If for exaomple you want to stress the smallness of the place you might say *There are little more than a thousand*.

But if you want to emphasise that it is large, you could say simply *There are more than a thousand*.

If it is in response to someone who has just claimed there were a thousand, then *There were a few more than that* would indicate that the place was larger than had just been implied.

***Few*** can sometimes be used paradoxically to indicate many - eg There were quite a few there

**Indeed your second sentence seems to suggest to me slightly
more people than your first does - simply from the way it is phrased**.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two choices, I would say
*There are a few more than 1000 inhabitants.*

But it would probably be more natural to say
*The population is a little over 1000.*